# Find all keys/names of a Freebase object?

Tags: search, freebase

I am trying to figure out how to query [freebase](http://www.freebase.com/) (or their [data dumps](http://download.freebase.com/datadumps/)) for a certain person or company name and get back a list of all the other "keys" or "names" for that item. I want to use the results to prevent duplicate tags in my content organization.

How do I [query freebase](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor) for all the names of a given item?

For example, [this page on IBM](http://www.freebase.com/inspect/en/ibm) lists the following names (or "keys") for the term "IBM".

- International_Business_Machines
- IBM
- IBM_computer
- IBM_Japan_Ltd
- IBM_Machines
- IBM_Software_Group
- etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will get you all the keys:

```
{
  "id": "/en/ibm",
  "key" : []
}
```

If you just want the ones from English Wikipedia, you can use:

```
{
  "id": "/en/ibm",
  "key" : [
    "namespace" : "/wikipedia/en",
    "value" : null
  ]
}
```

You can try them out in the query editor at http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor and click "mqlread" (top right) to get it transformed into a raw API call that you can use in your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Skud! I knew there must be a simple solution but I tried reworking all the example queries and I couldn't figure it out. I also never thought about "junk" keys that may show up - so perhaps I'll always use the second query you gave to make sure that I only get back valid results that someone at wikipedia has approved as a good name for the item. I wonder if I can find this data in the dump and just pre-process it myself to save all these queries.

Comment: Also, if you want to get the full list from the data dump you could download the quad dump and look for lines of the form:<ID> /type/object/key /wikipedia/en <Name>